# How to write a java program that will change my IE settings

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I need to create a Java program (inside the standalone application). When I execute that Java program, it has to change the my IE settings. Below I am attached screen shoot.

[image]

In that above screen shoot I have to change 256 to 1024 using Java program.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Seems like a strange thing to do

Comment: [Find the setting you want to modify in the registry](http://superuser.com/questions/91247/where-is-the-registry-location-for-ie-settings) then [change the setting's value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java).

Comment: can you please tell me programatically.i am new to java.

Comment: Can any one guide me